# Pause music player on a phone call and again resume it after phone call in android

Tags: android

I am using `android.media.MediaPlayer` object to play audio files in my app. Everything works fine but when a phone call comes while a song is playing the app does not pause the media player and you can hear the song during the phone call. Please tell me how to pause media player on a phone call and again resume it after call is ended.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `PhoneStateListener` to find out when the phone is in use.

Answer (score 3):

here is the permanent solution. Use audiomanager for getting audio focus. When call comes it calls AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT and you can pause the media player in that method. After call it calls AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN method so just call mediaplayer.start method .

```
private AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener  afChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
            mMediaPlayer.start();}

else if(focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT){

                mMediaPlayer.pause();
 }
```

Comment: this code is invalid..?

Answer (score 2):

When your Activity (or service) is interrupted by the phone call place `MediaPlayer#pause()` into `Activity#onPause` and code that resumes playing into `Activity#onResume` I think the problem may be that the MediaPlayer is executed in its own thread and when your Activity is paused it doesn't mean that MediaPlayer is automatically paused as well

Comment: The problem with this is that if the user changes activities within the application it will also pause the music.

Comment: I agree with Mark below - at that point you can use PhoneStateListener to detect if pause is due to phone usage

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) in your Application like so:

```
private PhoneStateListener mPhoneListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        try {
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    pauseStream();
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    resumeStream();
                    break;
                default:
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};
```

Then you need to set it up in your onCreate() or in your onStartCommand() method in case of a Service:

```
        radioStream.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        radioStream.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer stream) {
                telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                telephonyManager.listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
                isMusicPlaying = true;
                isServiceRunning = true;
                stream.start();
            }
        });
        try {
            radioStream.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            streamErrorHandler();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            streamErrorHandler();
        }
```

and you can implement your version of the following methods:

```
public static void pauseStream() {
    if (isServiceRunning) {
        if (radioStream.isPlaying()) {
            isMusicPlaying = false;
            radioStream.pause();
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "service isn't running");
    }
}

public static void resumeStream() {
    if (isServiceRunning) {
        if (!radioStream.isPlaying()) {
            isMusicPlaying = true;
            radioStream.start();
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "service isn't running");
    }
}
```

**radioStream** is your static [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) object. I am using this within a service so you can drop out the **isServiceRunning** but this should work for anyone's case.

Comment: Do I need to include some permission or telephony-related tags in AndroidManifest.xml to use this code?

Comment: @MMazzon normally i put the following safe permissions: 

android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,
android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS,
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

and if you use it for online streams then also:

android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
android.permission.INTERNET

for http streams you will need to add: 
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to your <application> tag

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  My HTC Desire HD would stop the music when phone call arrived but does not resume after hang up. I found that is caused by the Viber application and when i removed "Viber", everything went back to normal. Now when I receive a call the music pauses and resumes after i finish talking.