# Pause song when phone rings

Tags: android

I am pretty new to android development.

I wish to pause the multimedia whenever the phone rings and then start again when the call ends.

how can that be done?

Comment: Have you ever read about Activity Lifecycle? [Managing the Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle)

Comment: [Exact duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838055)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), which is notified, when the phone receives a call. [Here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) you can find a Tutorial on this.

Answer (score 1):

Here there is my implementation example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnAudioFocusChangeListener {

    private AudioManager mAudioManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
        ...
    }

    @Override
     public void onDestroy(){
         super.onDestroy();
         ...
         mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);
         ...
     }


    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        if(focusChange<=0) {
            //LOSS -> PAUSE
        } else {
            //GAIN -> PLAY
        }
    }   
}
```

I hope it's helpful for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

As per this answer: [Pause music player on a phone call and again resume it after phone call in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838055/pause-music-player-on-a-phone-call-and-again-resume-it-after-phone-call-in-androi)

It would be easier to use a

> PhoneStateListener

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html