# How to pause music when phone rings, sms is received, etc?

Tags: android, audio

I'm trying to detect android sounds and pause my app's music (temporarily or permanently) while they make noise.

This code appears to do nothing (*stop* pauses the music and *p* writes to the log), it never gets called:

```
public class PollyPrissyPants extends Activity implements OnAudioFocusChangeListener {
    // Blah blah blah
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int mal) {
        p("--CHANGE!!!--" + mal);
        stop();
    }
    // Yada yada yada
}
```

Do I have to set it up somewhere else as well? Is @Override relevant?

I haven't tried PhoneStateListener but if possible I don't want to have to treat phone calls, alarms, notifications, games, etc separately. I'm using vibrate for now but it sucks as a solution. If I get called, I have to answer and then quickly get to my app and pause it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pause song when phone rings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016800/pause-song-when-phone-rings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register the `OnAudioFocusListener` with the `AudioManager`:

```
audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audio.requestAudioFocus(this,
      AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

The `this` parameter is a reference to the class implementing `OnAudioFocusListener`.

Comment: Awesome! Worked perfectly :) Does that mean I should do this whenever I start/stop music, like change the request, at least to be polite to other apps?

Comment: You should only have to request audio focus once when the Activity or Service is created.  But it's a good idea to do it, so there aren't two applications trying to play music at the same time.