# Controling sound from app and incoming calls and SMS

Tags: android, sms, call, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

I am making a music player where I need to stream some music from URL.

Anyway, I want to control sound from application when I have incoming call or when I recive SMS.

I found that there could be two ways how to do it, with AudioManager and audio focus and with Telephony Manager.

But am not sure which way is better to do it?

Comment: I have used audioManager in the past and it works fine.

Comment: Could you post your code for audioManager? If it work, I will accept your answer.

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with it? I mean how you want to use AudioManager?

Comment: I want to use it for online radio streaming application. So, if app detecets call, stop music from playing, and play sound from call or sms.

Comment: I don't see a reason to use audioManager in this case. You simply have to detect a incoming call using Telephony Manager and on call detection simply pause your music.

Comment: Cool, and what about incoming SMS or notifications sounds?

Comment: I read some post where user didn't actually want to pause music for a simple 3 sec notification sound so I never bothered about it. I'll try and find out for you about how to pause music in case of any notification tone.

Comment: Okey, that makes sense about notifications. But, what about inocoming SMS? How to handle that?

Comment: SMS/other apps sound actually means Notification sound (since all show update in notification), I might be wrong though.

Comment: Found a perfect answer for your problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/6562880/1979347. This might be what you need.

Comment: I searched google using `music pause sms received` and found that music is automatically interrupted when SMS is received. Since I haven't tried it myself, maybe first you should check out if it is true or not.

Comment: Great stuff men! Thank you a lot. :) Anyway, if you want write some answer below, and I will accept it. Maybe it will help someone.

Comment: I tried to include all of our chat to an answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to pause music while you receive and incoming call then you can simply use **TelephonyManager** to detect an incoming call and pause the music.

Also if you want to pause music while you get any notification sound then you can see the answer [How to pause music when phone rings, sms is received, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6562880/1979347). It fits that need. Also on searching Google using query `music pause sms received`, I found that many users complained that Android OS itself pause the music while any notification sound is received. Also there was no setting to turn that off. Since I never tried it personally, I can't tell you on which versions that bug was present. You can research yourself or may ask a new question here, hopefully some knows more than myself.