# Pause app if phone is ringing

Tags: java, android

Just finished my mediaplayer app, but if I have the app running and the phone rings, it continues playing. Is there any way I can pause the player when the phone rings, and the resume playing after the call is ended? Or maybe exit the app if the phone rings?

Comment: looks same but to final solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838055/pause-music-player-on-a-phone-call-and-again-resume-it-after-phone-call-in-andro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

few suggestion

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

[Pause music player on a phone call and again resume it after phone call in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838055/pause-music-player-on-a-phone-call-and-again-resume-it-after-phone-call-in-andro)

[Pause song when phone rings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016800/pause-song-when-phone-rings)